# Python syntax multi line string in vim

Tags: python, vim

Can someone explain me why is this happening in vim? My multi line string starts at line 3 and ends at line 9. For some reason vim still thinks lines 10 and 11 are part of the string.

[image: vim highlight multi line string]

Sometimes, if I add more text or reopen the file, it starts working again.

I am not using any special plugins.

I've tried different vim versions, and this problem does not go away.

Any ideas?

Comment: Fair question but why comment out those functions at all?  They don't actually do anything when you use the `pass` keyword.  In any case try adding an extra space between the first function and the multi-line comment block.

Comment: Try to press ctrl+l (lowercase L) That command will redraw the screen. Sometimes vim is a bit slow updating.

Comment: @alex This is just an example, it could be any function. Sometimes when I add an extra space it works, but later it randomly stops working.

Comment: @blues Refreshing vim didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Try replacing the three single quotes with three double quotes: `'''` to `"""`.  It's too early to tell, but it seems to be working for me so far.